# error C2375: 'printf' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\stdio.h

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution which is originally compiled for VS2015. I'm trying to compile the same code in VS2012. To do this, I've created a new solution, added these projects to the new solution and changed the project properties Platform Toolset to v110 instead of v140.

While building this solution, I am facing the error:

**error C2375: 'printf' : redefinition; different linkage   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\stdio.h  271**

The line which seems to be causing this error is:

**_Check_return_opt_ _CRTIMP int __cdecl printf(_In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ const char * _Format, ...);**

I'm unable to figure out the root cause of this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` add at the beginning:

Comment: hey, that works. thanks. but why does it work without the #include <stdio.h> in VS2015

Comment: In MSVC, the header file is compiled into a pre-compiled header file (as `stdafx.h`). Therefore I guess that it did not work on project transition.

Comment: the actual reason for the error is still going over my head. any explanation on this or references will be of great help.